# Is This a "Do My Work For Me" question?

Tags: discussion

See here:
[Custom page template to display all image attachments](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53605/inserting-all-picture/53606#comment68987_53606)

Is this question becoming a "do my work for me" type question? I'm going to go ahead and try to answer it fully, but for future reference, is the OP going too far in his scope? It seems to be "not a real question"/"too localized", or something, given the basic nature of his follow-up questions.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that question is a "can I haz the codez pleaeazzz" type of question.  I just don't think the OP didn't even really know where to start.

I answered a [question recently](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/53495/251) that I thought was going to be one of those do my work for me ones but instead of writing out the code I suggested some hooks and a starting point.  I was very surprised that the OP did the research and came up with a solution.  He even came back and updated my answer with his code.  Hopefully he will stick around because we need more users like him.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no.

From the looks of things, the OP just wasn't sure how to ask the question.  I think it's more of a case of not knowing what you don't know than asking us to do work for them.

Comment: Perhaps "do my work for me" wasn't the best description. My intuition tells me that it's somewhere in the realm of and/or "not a real question" and/or "too localized". (I think fielding questions about "where do I put this code?" and how to *use* custom page template isn't constructive for WPSE.)

Answer (score 0):

The question is not too wide, I think. The asker just doesn't know much PHP. I don't see a problem here. I had a [similar situation today](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53561/73) and my thoughts were: Sending the asker away to understand the rest would be less helpful than explaining my solution with more details than usual.

Oh, and you can just stop responding in a conversation if it is getting too far away.